# Python: Multiindex recursive calculation

Tags: python, multi-index

I am relatively new to Python world, was wondering if someone can give me some pointers to resolve my query.

I have a multi index dataframe, sample below:

```
**IDENTIFIER_VALUE  TIME**  DATE    ASK PRICE   BID PRICE   ask bid
BE0000291972    08:17:14    19/02/2018  145.09  144.82  145.08  144.96
    08:17:18    19/02/2018  145.09  144.95  145.08  144.96
    08:17:18    19/02/2018  145.09  144.95  145.08  144.96
    08:18:18    19/02/2018  145.09  144.95  145.08  144.96
    08:22:18    19/02/2018  145.09  144.95  145.08  144.96
    08:43:18    19/02/2018  145.09  144.95  145.08  144.96
    08:51:18    19/02/2018  145.09  144.95  145.08  144.96
    09:00:18    19/02/2018  145.09  144.95  145.08  144.96
    09:06:18    19/02/2018  145.09  144.95  145.08  144.96
    09:08:18    19/02/2018  145.09  144.95  145.08  144.96
    09:15:18    19/02/2018  145.09  144.95  145.08  144.96
    09:16:18    19/02/2018  145.09  144.95  145.08  144.96
    09:27:18    19/02/2018  145.09  144.95  145.08  144.96
    09:28:18    19/02/2018  145.09  144.94  145.08  144.96
    09:42:18    19/02/2018  145.09  144.94  145.08  144.96
    09:44:18    19/02/2018  145.09  144.94  145.08  144.96
BE0000337460    10:45:04    19/02/2018  102.12  102.06  102.11  102.06
    11:04:04    19/02/2018  102.12  102.06  102.11  102.06
    11:23:04    19/02/2018  102.12  102.06  102.11  102.06
    11:31:04    19/02/2018  102.12  102.06  102.11  102.06
    11:43:04    19/02/2018  102.12  102.06  102.11  102.06
    11:57:04    19/02/2018  102.12  102.06  102.11  102.06
    12:04:04    19/02/2018  102.12  102.06  102.11  102.06
    12:14:04    19/02/2018  102.12  102.06  102.11  102.06
    12:41:04    19/02/2018  102.12  102.06  102.11  102.06
    12:50:04    19/02/2018  102.12  102.06  102.11  102.06
    12:57:04    19/02/2018  102.12  102.06  102.11  102.06
    13:08:04    19/02/2018  102.12  102.06  102.11  102.06
    13:11:04    19/02/2018  102.12  102.06  102.11  102.06
    13:33:04    19/02/2018  102.12  102.06  102.11  102.06
    13:48:04    19/02/2018  102.12  102.06  102.11  102.06
    14:03:04    19/02/2018  102.12  102.06  102.11  102.06
```

Question: I want to perform the below:

For each value at level 0 of the Index do the following:
1. Start from the first record. Example:

```
IDENTIFIER_VALUE    TIME    DATE    ASK PRICE   BID PRICE   ask bid
BE0000291972    08:17:14    19/02/2018  145.09  144.82  145.08  144.96
```

2. Look for all the records in the next 7 min with respect to the time on the first record. So based on above I want to pick all the records from 8:17:14 - 8:24:17 for the same security. So it should give me the following:

   IDENTIFIER_VALUE    TIME    DATE    ASK PRICE   BID PRICE   ask bid
   BE0000291972    08:17:14    19/02/2018  145.09  144.82  145.08  144.96
       08:17:18    19/02/2018  145.09  144.95  145.08  144.96
       08:17:18    19/02/2018  145.09  144.95  145.08  144.96
       08:18:18    19/02/2018  145.09  144.95  145.08  144.96
       08:22:18    19/02/2018  145.09  144.95  145.08  144.96
3. Want to do some calculations on this data set.
4. Repeat the step 1-3 using the second record. Repeat till the end of all the records in the dataset.

Groupby / resample will combine the records for the time frequency, but this is not what I am looking for. I want to extract the records for every 7 min with respect to each entry in the dataframe and do the calcs on that. Hope I am able to explain what I want.

Thanks In advance

Comment: You’re looking for a variation on a sliding window algorithm. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Thanks for replying back, as I am very new to Python (just 3 weeks) and not sure how to approach this. Could you please give me some pointers for sliding window what you suggested above?

Comment: I’m not near a computer now to break it down, but here is a way to solve the problem using the `pandas` library: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/20521/18265

Comment: Thanks Joel, I tried using .rolling('7min', min_periods=1) and it seems to be working on the first look. I will test it more to make sure it confirms my requirements.

Answer (score 0):

For illustrative purposes, here is a general solution that doesn't require 3rd party libraries:

```
from collections import deque
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


def sliding_window(it, size, dist=(lambda a, b: b - a), index=(lambda x: x)):
    q = deque()
    for item in it:
        i = index(item)
        while q and dist(q[0][0], i) >= size:
            yield [x for _, x in q]
            q.popleft()

        q.append((i, item))

    if q:
        yield [x for _, x in q]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import pprint
    pprint.pprint(list(sliding_window(
        [
            { "timestamp": "2018-01-18T04:00:00Z" },
            { "timestamp": "2018-01-18T04:00:01Z" },
            { "timestamp": "2018-01-18T04:03:00Z" },
            { "timestamp": "2018-01-18T04:04:00Z" },
            { "timestamp": "2018-01-18T04:10:00Z" },
            { "timestamp": "2018-01-18T04:24:00Z" },
            { "timestamp": "2018-01-18T04:28:00Z" }
        ],
        timedelta(minutes=7),
        index=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x["timestamp"], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
    )))
```

This outputs:

```
[[{'timestamp': '2018-01-18T04:00:00Z'},
  {'timestamp': '2018-01-18T04:00:01Z'},
  {'timestamp': '2018-01-18T04:03:00Z'},
  {'timestamp': '2018-01-18T04:04:00Z'}],
 [{'timestamp': '2018-01-18T04:00:01Z'},
  {'timestamp': '2018-01-18T04:03:00Z'},
  {'timestamp': '2018-01-18T04:04:00Z'}],
 [{'timestamp': '2018-01-18T04:03:00Z'}, {'timestamp': '2018-01-18T04:04:00Z'}],
 [{'timestamp': '2018-01-18T04:04:00Z'}, {'timestamp': '2018-01-18T04:10:00Z'}],
 [{'timestamp': '2018-01-18T04:10:00Z'}],
 [{'timestamp': '2018-01-18T04:24:00Z'}, {'timestamp': '2018-01-18T04:28:00Z'}]]
```

Comment: Thanks Joel, for taking time to answer my query. Let me digest this first :). Will keep you posted.